How do I fix XHR error when working withAJAX?
I am building a very simple Chat using Pusher and Laravel. Pusher is set and it works as it should. I am also trying to send a message to the broadcast route using AJAX and then show the message on my blade, but I am getting internal server error 500 and an XHR error every time I try to approach the broadcast post route.
This is my error:
homePage:97 XHR:

{readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …}

abort: ƒ ( statusText )

always: ƒ ()

catch: ƒ ( fn )

done: ƒ ()

fail: ƒ ()

getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ ()

getResponseHeader: ƒ ( key )

overrideMimeType: ƒ ( type )

pipe: ƒ ( /* fnDone, fnFail, fnProgress */ )

progress: ƒ ()

promise: ƒ ( obj )

readyState: 4

responseText: "<script> Sfdump = window.Sfdump || (function (doc

setRequestHeader: ƒ ( name, value )

state: ƒ ()

status: 500

statusCode: ƒ ( map )

statusText: "Internal Server Error"

then: ƒ ( onFulfilled, onRejected, onProgress )




This is my code:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://js.pusher.com/8.2.0/pusher.min.js"></script>
    
    <script src="https://js.pusher.com/7.2/pusher.min.js"></script>
    <script src=" https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.js"></script>
   
</head>
<body>
     

    <h1>home page</h1>

    
    <div>
      @include('receive', ['message' => "Hey!"])
      @include('receive', ['message' => "I am here"])
    </div>
    
    <form method="POST">
      <input type="text" id="message" name="message" placeholder="Enter message..." autocomplete="off">
      <button type="submit">SEND</button>
    </form>

    <script>
  
      // Enable pusher logging - don't include this in production
      Pusher.logToConsole = true;
      var pusher = new Pusher('d626d6f2f79dccc3bd38', {
          cluster: 'eu'
        });
        
      var channel = pusher.subscribe('public');
   
   /*    channel.bind('chat', function (data) {
    $.post("/receive", {
      _token:  '{{csrf_token()}}',
      message: data.message,
    })
     .done(function (res) {
       $(".messages > .message").last().after(res);
       $(document).scrollTop($(document).height());
     });
  });*/
     
      //Broadcast messages
      //Broadcast messages
  $("form").submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
      url:     "/broadcast",
      method:  'POST',
      headers: {
        'X-Socket-Id': pusher.connection.socket_id
      },
      data:    {
        _token:  '{{csrf_token()}}',
        message: $("form #message").val(),
      }
    }).done(function (res) {
      $(".messages > .message").last().after(res);
      $("form #message").val('');
      $(document).scrollTop($(document).height());
    });
  });




    </script>
</body>
</html>

Here are my storage logs:
#49 C:\laragon\www\echo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(119): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request)) #50 C:\laragon\www\echo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(175): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure)) #51 C:\laragon\www\echo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(144): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
And these are my server logs:
my error logs looks like this: 024] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 24092:tid 380] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads. [Wed Jun 05 16:47:24.255676 2024] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 23176:tid 360] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited. [Wed Jun 05 18:21:43.896426 2024] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8452:tid 368] AH00422: Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server. [Wed Jun 05 18:21:45.920607 2024] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 24092:tid 380] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited
I changed php memory in php.ini. Now it is 512 MB.
I am not sure what to do.

"500 Internal Server Error" is a generic error message informing you that the server crashed while processing the request. Beyond that, it's (intentionally) meaningless, and is of very little use for debugging, diagnosing or resolving problems. You need to check the error logs on the server (or enable on-screen error reporting, if it's a development environment) to try and find the underlying exception message. Once you've got that, you stand a chance of identifying the problem, and then moving on to trying to fix it.

my error logs looks like this: 024] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 24092:tid 380] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Wed Jun 05 16:47:24.255676 2024] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 23176:tid 360] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited.
[Wed Jun 05 18:21:43.896426 2024] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8452:tid 368] AH00422: Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
[Wed Jun 05 18:21:45.920607 2024] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 24092:tid 380] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited.

But in my console I that there is a red line the jquery.js:
try {
 // Do send the request (this may raise an exception)
 xhr.send( options.hasContent && options.data || null );
} catch ( e ) {

 // trac-14683: Only rethrow if this hasn't been notified as an error yet
 if ( callback ) {
  throw e;
 }                                                                                                                 Maybe it is something with the library or browser, I am not sure. I switched to other browser but it is still the same.


The error is somewhere in your PHP code, not JS. HTTP 500 is a server error. [edit] your question to include any relevant code or logs. I don't think your Apache log is the most likely source, and nothing you've shown looks massively relevant, it just looks like the regular startup and shutdown logs. Try PHP/Laravel logs

#49 C:\laragon\www\echo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(119): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#50 C:\laragon\www\echo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(175): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#51 C:\laragon\www\echo\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(144): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))

These are some of my last logs.

As I said above, can you please [edit] your question with the log info, so it can be formatted properly and is in context. This is not a discussion forum. See also [ask].

None of these logs appear to be your php/laravel error logs. https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/logging
